# AppStore application sumbission xcode 4.2 failure because of launch image

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to submit my first iOS application to AppStore using xCode 4.2.
I always get status of : "Invalid binary".
For the first time I got the following explanation:
"
iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. New iPhone apps and app updates submitted targeting iOS 6 and above must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images
"

but when I add the requested launch image I get another failure with following explanation:
"
Invalid Launch Image - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later.
"
My target OS is iOS 5.
Please help

Comment: i think the issue is with iphone 5 splash screen image you need to upload the splash screen for iphone 5 with correct size and valid image.

Comment: You app is not targeting for iOS 6 ??

Comment: You need to change the target to iOS6.0 or higher and build the binary for the same.

Comment: For iPhone5 you need to add the image with this name Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: Refer to this link for required images according to your target devices. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to target for iOS 6  as iPhone5 is shipped with iOS6, then you can add the launch image with -568h size.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting iOS 5, its not an issue. Even you can submit a app targeting iOS 4.3.

Issue is, your application is not optimized for iPhone5, you must add the launch images for iPhone 5 and iPhone 5 launch image resolution(pixel) should be exact 640x1136 (png). You should add it from Target>Launch Images.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did it, than I got another failure message: Invalid Launch Image - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later. Mightbe you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Now apple will accept apps that will support iOS 6.0 or later along with previous iOS version support. For that, you need launch image for retina display (iPhone 5 as well.)

You need following launch images for iPhone(only):

```
640 x 1136
640 x 960
320 x 480
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set target for latest iOS 6 and for icon , image size for app store please follow the below URL

[iPhone , iPad icon size for Retina and non retina](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages)